# Создание XML из c#

Tags: c#, xml

Всем привет. Создаю XMl.

Ошибка: System.ArgumentException: "Невозможно вставить в качестве дочернего узла ни сам этот узел, ни его предка."

```
/*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> */
            //создание объявления (декларации) документа
            XmlDeclaration XmlDec = XmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
            //добавляем в документ
            XmlDoc.AppendChild(XmlDec);
            //создание корневого элемента 
            XmlElement GetInform = XmlDoc.CreateElement("GetInform");

            XmlElement elem_getReferenceSPV4664 = XmlDoc.CreateElement("ns0:getReferenceSPV4664");
            elem_getReferenceSPV4664.SetAttribute("xmlns:ns0", "http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/");
            elem_getReferenceSPV4664.AppendChild(elem_getReferenceSPV4664); //Тут ошибка

            XmlElement elem_ReferenceSPV4664Request = XmlDoc.CreateElement("ns0:ReferenceSPV4664Request");
            GetInform.AppendChild(elem_ReferenceSPV4664Request);

            XmlElement elem_idUser = XmlDoc.CreateElement("idUser");
            elem_ReferenceSPV4664Request.AppendChild(elem_idUser);
            elem_idUser.AppendChild(XmlDoc.CreateTextNode("0"));


            XmlElement elem_vagons = XmlDoc.CreateElement("vagons");
            elem_ReferenceSPV4664Request.AppendChild(elem_vagons);

            XmlElement elem_vagon = XmlDoc.CreateElement("vagon");
            elem_vagons.AppendChild(elem_vagon);

            elem_vagon.AppendChild(XmlDoc.CreateTextNode("75142901"));
```

Вариант 2:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
            // создаем первый элемент
            XElement Request = new XElement("GetInform");
            // создаем атрибут
            XAttribute getReferenceSPV4664 = new XAttribute("ns0:" + "getReferenceSPV4664 xmlns:ns0", "http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/"); //Тут ошибка
            XElement ReferenceSPV4664Request = new XElement("ReferenceSPV4664Request");
            XElement idUser = new XElement("idUser", "0");
            XElement vagons = new XElement("vagons");

            // добавляем атрибут и элементы в первый элемент
            Request.Add(getReferenceSPV4664);
            Request.Add(ReferenceSPV4664Request);
            Request.Add(idUser);
```

System.Xml.XmlException: "Знак ":", шестнадцатеричное значение 0x3A, не может использоваться в именах."

Сам XML Должен быть вида.

```
<GetInform>
<ns0:getReferenceSPV4664 xmlns:ns0="http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/">
<ns0:ReferenceSPV4664Request>
<idUser>0</idUser>
<vagons>
<vagon>50032382</vagon>
</vagons>
</ns0:ReferenceSPV4664Request>
</ns0:getReferenceSPV4664>
</GetInform>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное, самый простой вариант, который получает равносильный XML, такой:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
XElement Request = new XElement("GetInform");
XNamespace ns0 = "http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/";
XElement getReferenceSPV4664 = new XElement(ns0 + "getReferenceSPV4664");
XElement ReferenceSPV4664Request = new XElement(ns0 + "ReferenceSPV4664Request");
XElement idUser = new XElement("idUser", 0);
XElement vagons = new XElement("vagons");
XElement vagon = new XElement("vagon", 50032382);

Request.Add(getReferenceSPV4664);
getReferenceSPV4664.Add(ReferenceSPV4664Request);
ReferenceSPV4664Request.Add(idUser);
ReferenceSPV4664Request.Add(vagons);
xdoc.Add(Request);
```

Это же можно записать компактнее:

```
var ns0 = (XNamespace)"http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/";
var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("GetInform",
        new XElement(ns0 + "getReferenceSPV4664",
            new XElement(ns0 + "ReferenceSPV4664Request",
                new XElement("idUser", 0),
                new XElement("vagons",
                    new XElement("vagon", 50032382))))));
```

Если вы хотите строго такое имя атрибута, как в вашем примере, нужно воспользоваться [примером из документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/control-namespace-prefixes):

```
var ns0 = (XNamespace)"http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/";
var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("GetInform",
        new XElement(ns0 + "getReferenceSPV4664",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns0", ns0.NamespaceName),
            new XElement(ns0 + "ReferenceSPV4664Request",
                new XElement("idUser", 0),
                new XElement("vagons",
                    new XElement("vagon", 50032382))))));
```

Результат:

[image: лучше один раз увидеть]